# How to calculate check digit for Barcode 128 Auto php

Tags: php, barcode, code128

I have a string which uses 128B and 128C conversion. ANCV0005YRF01234. 
So

```
ANCV = 128B
0005 = 128C
YRF0= 128B
1234= 128 C
```

Cant use code 128 Auto  as it converts the 0 after F into 128C (which i dont want.). At the moment using two different scripts and concatenating the barcode images,Need to calculate the check digit for that. Not sure how the check digit will be generated ?. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It costs you three characters to switch from B to C to B and back to C and by using 128C you are only saving four characters in your example. That's a total of 1 net barcode character. Are you sure it's worth the complexity you are adding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got sum of characters by weights (rightmost column) from your example string = 5468 % 103 = 9 for a checksum if you want to switch back and forth.

[image: Start Code B = 104, Switch to C = 99, Switch to B = 100]

Comment: Thanks bud .

http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/BarcodeStringBuilderExample.aspx

the above link helps decode the string for their respective subset. was quite lucky to come across this kind of masterpiece .,